# изъять данные из строки json

Tags: python, json, python-3.6

вот к примеру такая структура:

```
u'status': u'success',
u'photos': [{
    u'url': u'http://farm1.static.flickr.com/41/104498903_bad315cee0.jpg',
    u'width': 500,
    u'tags': [{
        u'eye_left': {u'y': 31.2, u'x': 55.6},
        u'confirmed': False,
        u'uids': [{u'confidence': 34, u'uid': u'guido@testns'}],
        u'width': 13.6,
        u'yaw': -45,
        u'manual': False,
        u'height': 18.13,
        u'threshold': 30,
        u'mouth_center': {u'y': 43.47, u'x': 52.6},
        u'nose': {u'y': 36.53, u'x': 53.4},
        u'eye_right': {u'y': 30.93, u'x': 48.0},
        u'pitch': 0,
        u'tid': u'TEMP_F@08e31221350a43d267be01d500f10086_1d12ece6a6ea2_48.20_35.73_0_1',
        u'attributes': {
            u'gender': {u'confidence': 47, u'value': u'male'},
            u'smiling': {u'confidence': 85, u'value': u'false'},
            u'glasses': {u'confidence': 27, u'value': u'false'},
            u'dark_glasses': {u'confidence': 89, u'value': u'false'},
            u'face': {u'confidence': 71, u'value': u'true'}
        },
        u'recognizable': True,
        u'roll': 3,
        u'center': {u'y': 35.73, u'x': 48.2}
    }],
    u'pid': u'F@08e31221350a43d267be01d572dc824b_1d12ece6a6ea2',
    u'height': 375
}],
```

Как мне получить в поле uids значения confidence=34,uid=guido@testns ?

Comment: Если у вас Python 3.6, то зачем вы используете литералы юникода?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
confidence = some_json_var['photos'][0]['tags'][0]['uids'][0]['confidence']
```

Аналогично для uid.